# Excel: spread the difference of two values between range of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using google spreadsheets, and filling a sheet like image below.
I want to know if there is a way to fill the cells C97-C110 (marked as red), in a way that is distributed evenly between 93 and 113. Is there a shortcut, or easy way to do this? Becasue I might need to do this a lot for different cells.

[image]

The expected result is something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning by distributed evenly, any sample result?

Comment: I updated the example

Answer (score 1):

Here is some useful shortcut you may use:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kin, I was hoping I could find a keyboard shortcut. So for example if I highlight a few cells and drag the mouse to the next cells, they will be automatically filled, with the desired increments.

Comment: There is some useful keyboard shortcut you may use, Ctrl + D to fill down all the row based on first row, and Ctrl + R to fill in all the row to the right based on first left cell, see my example above